# Regex to allow square brackets in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm using [jquery-validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and validating a URL.
Now the problem is it is not allowing this URL:

```
http://google.com?PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]
```

The issue in the URL is square brackets.

Here is the regex they are using to validate :

```
return this.optional(element) || /^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(value);
```

How to update this regex to allow square brackets "[]"?

Comment: Please explain that one long regex.

Comment: @Unihedron I too don't know :) It is written by the guy who wrote  jquery-validate plugin.

Comment: I would had loved to help you and try understand it to begin with, but there's no way I'm working through those 1187 characters (with occasional unicode literals) if you don't show \*some\* research effort.

Comment: tried on python..........its working fine der....

Comment: This seems to be a pure regex problem and nothing really to do with using the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: That's not really a valid URL, is it?  The brackets should be `%5B` and `%5D`.

Comment: @Sparky Yeah it doesn't seem to be a valid URL but thats the requirement.A user can not replace square brackets with %5B and %5D

Comment: Why would a user manually be typing in a complex URL query string in the first place, brackets or not.  Where does it come from?